# Installing strapi on Amazon Lightsail

Tags: node.js, strapi, amazon-lightsail

Can anyone point me with a step by step guide to install strapi on Amazon Lightsail, i've tried all the possible options but cant make it work.

1. I create a MEANT or NODE instance
2. Add a static IP
3. Install strapi
4. start strapi
   I now have to go to localhost(my ip) :1337 but no answer
   I have no experience with reverse proxy or ngnix servers, so maybe it's obvious to any with some experience.
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a process manager and edit .env file.

1. [Install PM2](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/process-manager.html#install-pm2) and use .env files.
2. Then create [ecosystem.config.js](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) file

It's already documented in [AWS general guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html), *Amazon Lightsail* has no difference. Just jump first a few steps

That's all.